# Array destructuring with a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to concat (with uniques values) two arrays and if the second array sometimes is a string.

Maybe it have a bug, but these are my three tryings:

```js
let a = 'abcdefg'
// First try
[...new Set([...[], ...(typeof(a) == 'string'? [a]: a))]
// Second try
[...new Set([...[], [(typeof(a) == 'string'? ...[a]: ...a)]]
// Third try
[...new Set([...[], (typeof(a) == 'string'? ...[a]: ...a)]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well -  and some use cases with their result.

Comment: `...[]` makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
[...new Set([...[], ...(typeof a === 'string' ? [a] : a))]
```

take, watch the round, square, round and squere closing brackets at the end.

```
[...new Set([...[], ...(typeof a === 'string' ? [a] : a)])]
//                                                      ^
```

```js
let a = 'abcdefg'

console.log([...new Set([...[], ...(typeof a === 'string' ? [a] : a)])]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using spread, you can use [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), because it treats combine arrays and values in the same way:

```js
const a = 'abcdefg'
console.log([...new Set([].concat([], a))])
console.log([...new Set([].concat([], [a]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if the `a` parameter is a string, and not a collection, searching unique values and the need for a Set is moot. Then you could short circuit as `typeof a === 'string' ? [a] : [...new Set(a)]`

```js
let a = 'abcdefg'

const createArr = a => typeof a === 'string' ? [a] : [...new Set(a)];

console.log(createArr(a));
console.log(createArr([a,a,'aa']));
```

Comment: For the record, I like the solution by @OriDrori better ;)